# Advice for NN Architecture

Tags: classification, neural-networks

Could someone give me advice on the architecture of NN for the following task: I have a list of agents (with some properties) and a list of activities in time of each agent (an every agent has a different number of records of the activities). I need to divide agents on two classes. I have big amount of labeled data.

The way my friends do the task is the following:

- Manually figure out and extract features form list of activities for each agent (like max, mean time between records and etc.)
- Add those features to the table of agents
- Use random forest classifier

Their approach works quite well, but I dislike the idea of manually inventing and extracting features from lists of activities. As I understand multi-layer neural networks are good in extracting features and I want to use this advantage

However, my first problem is: each agent has different number of activities. As a result, amount of data is different for each agent. How to form input layer of NN?

I'm not sure about how to be with the fact that those activities have quite clear periodic patterns. Should I do something special about it?

I would be glad to hear any ideas. Thank you

Comment: Can you display a portion of these time series?

Comment: I have 2000 classified agents, not a lot actually :(. As for activities I have about 7 millions totally, however they distributed quite unevenly  among agents (some even has only 1 activity record)

Comment: It's hard for me to show time series now

Comment: I would suggest that you adopt a RNN/LSTM inspired network which can take account the temporal nature of the activities: when it starts for some guy, when it stops, how the start and stop for one guy is correlated to the start and stop for another guy, etc.

Comment: I also thought about RNN, but it's hard to teach it (although I didn't try, I afraid of exploding gradients and other difficulties). Could I somehow adapt feed forward NN? (may be with just one hidden layer). For example, if it were the same data for each agent, I would try just to feed it into the input layer at once. What about taking the input layer which size equals the maximum number of activities for an agent, and fill it with zeros if some agent doesn't have enough?

Comment: LSTM deals with problem of exploding gradients. You can get some inspiration by this approach: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.04122.pdf ;
In this case too, each 'candidate' has not the same number of values, so you can encode in your inputs the candidate id (with an indicator vector (0,0,...,1,0,...,0)) and the duration, i.e. the time between two activities or two events, the start/end of an activity. This architecture will consider (like an autoregressive (AR) model) the correlation between the 'candidates'.

Comment: This problem doesn't seem to be about time series.